# Problem with Springer bibliography style(spbasic + natbib)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am writing a paper to a Springer journal and I am trying to use their `\bibliographystyle{spbasic}`.  I want to sort citation by appearance, hence the first citation in the article should be cited with [1] and second with [2] and so on. But citation is sort by the reference's alphabetically order.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\begin{document}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
.............. \cite{S1} .......... \cite{S2}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic} 
\bibliography{sssat.bib}   % name your BibTeX data base

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create and use a modified version of the `spbasic` bibliography style.

- Find the file `spbasic.bst` on your computer. Create a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `spbasic_unsort.bst`.
- Open the file `spbasic_unsort.bst` in a text editor.
- Find the two lines that start with `SORT` (note: uppercase is important), and comment out -- or simply delete -- both of these lines.
- Save the file `spbasic_unsort.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by your tex distribution. If you choose the latter method, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{spbasic}` to `\bibliographystyle{spbasic_unsort}`. Then, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

This technique also works for the `\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}`, where the same problem is observed. There is only one instance of a line (line number 1462) starting with `SORT` in the file `spmpsci.bst`. Either we can comment or delete that line.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: I delete the line but it doesn't work. I think i make some mistakes. Can you please see https://ideone.com/akgvBN ? 
Can you tell me the exact line number? @Mico

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul - One of the instructions said, "Find the two lines that start with `SORT` ...". Please look for lines 1572 and 1625.

Comment: If removing lines starting with SORT does not work, that's probably because you did not remove temporary files created by LaTeX.

Comment: @SouravMondal -- Many thanks for this additional thought. It may be worth pointing out that the approach proposed in my answer should work with virtually all bibliography styles, not just `spbasic` and `spmpsci`. The only major thing to keep track of is how `SORT`-lines need to be deleted (or commented out).

Comment: Thank you. You saved my life.