# No .bbl file generated in the Springer document class svjour3 and bibliography style spmpscis when using Texmaker

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texmaker, sv-classes

I want to write a Springer conference article. I have download its template but when I create a new bibliography file `bibliography.bib` and I add a citation, the following message is shown:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `wang2012mathematical' on page 1 undefined on input lin
e 51.
No file "Draft Paper".bbl.
[1{C:/Users/---/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
]
("Draft Paper.aux") )
```

The result is as follows:

[image: Image of the output, showing a question mark where the citation number should appear.]
My LaTeX file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Draft Paper.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore

\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass [twocolumn,draft] {svjour3} 
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%title 
\title{Network interface selection}
%\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}
\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
\maketitle


 

\begin{abstract}

 \cite{wang2012mathematical}.

\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
\end{abstract}


\bibliographystyle{spmpscis}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
                
\end{document}
```

What is the problem? How can I add the references?

Comment: Have you run the bibtex command? If not, go to Options > Configure Texmaker  > Quick Build and select the second option "PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf" and press Ok. Then build your document as normal. Return it to "PdfLaTeX + View PDF" when you're done (as compiling the bibliography takes a lot of time).

Comment: When I go to Options > Configure Texmaker > Quick Build and select the second option "PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf" and press Ok. I cant run it, and that message is shown:  "This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: Draft Paper.aux I couldn't open style file spmpscis.bst ---line 3 of file Draft Paper.aux : \bibstyle{spmpscis : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style file---while reading file Draft Paper.aux (There were 2 error messages)"

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

See the [answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312819/problem-with-springer-bibliography-stylespbasic-natbib)

Comment: @Tanvir still the same problem

Comment: Is the bibliographystyle `spmpscis` or `spmpsci`?

Comment: @Tanvir, spmpscis, my problem is not in SORT, my problem is that the citation is undefined

Comment: ""This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: Draft Paper.aux I couldn't open style file spmpscis.bst ---line 3 of file Draft Paper.aux : \bibstyle{spmpscis : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style file---while reading file Draft Paper.aux (There were 2 error messages)".

The error  message is telling you that it cannot locate bibliography style file ```spmpscis.bst```.

Answer (score 1):

Using Springer `LaTeX` template downloaded from [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates), I could compile your `tex` file. Few changes: a) I could not find the bibliography style `spmpscis`, instead I have used `spmpsci`which came with the downloaded  Springer template. b) added a `sample.bib` to generate the bibliography.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Draft Paper.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore

\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass [twocolumn,draft] {svjour3} 
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%title 
\title{Network interface selection}
%\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}
\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}

 % \cite{wang2012mathematical} % uncomment it when you compile 

 % citation as in 'sample.bib'

 \cite{Berger84,Berger03}

\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
\end{abstract}


%\bibliographystyle{spmpscis} % not available; so commented
%\bibliography{Bibliography} % uncomment it when you compile

\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}
\bibliography{sample}


\end{document}
```

The bibliography file `sample.bib` is as follows:

```
    @ARTICLE{Berger84,
     author = {{Berger}, M.~A.},
     title = {Rigorous new limits on magnetic helicity dissipation in the solar corona},
     journal = {Geophys. Astrophys. Fluid. Dyn.},
     year = 1984,
     volume = 30,
     pages = {79-104},
 }

    @INPROCEEDINGS{Berger03,
    author = {{Berger}, M.~A.},
    title = "Topological quantities in magnetohydrodynamics",
    booktitle = {Advances in Nonlinear Dynamics},
    publisher = {Taylor and Francis Group},
    address = "London",
    editor = {{Ferriz-Mas}, A. and {N{\'u}{\~n}ez}, M.},
    year = 2003,
    pages = {345-383},
    adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2003and..book..345B&amp;db_key=PHY},
  adsnote = {Provided by the NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```