# three authors followed by "et al" on BibTeX reference list

Tags: bibtex, author-number

I found this answer to a very similar question: [BibTeX: How to reduce long author lists to “Firstauthor et al.”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-to-reduce-long-author-lists-to-firstauthor-et-al#)

However, the proposed solution did not work for me. I have a style provided by the publisher who, at the same time explains that the reference authors should be truncated after the third author (followed by et al)

in the file I found the `{  namesleft #1 >` and changed it as instructed in that reply but it did not work. Can you help me?

````
{ 'bibinfo :=
 duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
 's :=
 "" 't :=
 #1 'nameptr :=
 s num.names$ 'numnames :=
 numnames 'namesleft :=
   { namesleft #0 > }
   { s nameptr
     "{vv~}{ll}{ f{}}{ jj}"
     format.name$
     remove.dots
     bibinfo bibinfo.check
     't :=
     nameptr #1 >
      % {
       %  namesleft #1 >
nameptr #1 >
        {
         nameptr #3
         #1 + =
         numnames #5
         > and
           { "others" 't :=
             #1 'namesleft := }
           'skip$
         if$
         namesleft #1 >
           { ", " * t * }
           {
             "," *
             s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
               { 't := }
               { pop$ }
             if$
             t "others" =
               {
                 " " * bbl.etal *
               }
               { " " * t * }
             if$
           }
         if$
       }
       't
     if$
     nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
     namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
   }
 while$
 } if$
} ```
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ at present. If it's a nonstandard style, please indicate if it's available online.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the instructions in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26582/5001) -- shameless self-citation alert! -- correctly? Looking at the code you posted, it looks like the second instance of `nameptr #1 >` doesn't belong.

Comment: you are right: the second instance of nameptr #1 > does not belong to the correct instructions: I realized it and corrected but still it does not wotk. The style is available on the Springer website in a zipfile at: https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20568/data/v8

Comment: The link you furnished provides three bst files: `spbasic`, `spphys`, and `spmpsci`. Which one do *you* employ?

Comment: spbasic, sorry: I should have specified it!

Comment: Please also clarify what "did not work for me" entails. E.g., do you get an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: It just lists all the authors in the bibliography, rather than the first three followed by "et al": same problem that in the related question I linked

Comment: summarizing: the publisher provides the style but says that we should indicate the first three authors followed by et al; the provided style, instead, lists all the authors instead of the first three followed by et al.

Comment: Mico, you are great! Thank you

Comment: If my answer has fully addressed the typesetting issue(s) you were looking to solve, feel free to give it an "accept" checkmark. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The OP has indicated in a comment that he/she uses the `spbasic` bibliography style that's supplied by Springer.

To achieve the desired formatting -- to show the names of all authors if an entry has *at most 4* authors, but to show the first three authors only followed by "et al." if the entry has *more than 4* authors -- I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Make a copy of `spbasic.bst` and call the copy, say, `spbasic85.bst`.
- Open the file `spbasic85.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit tex files will be fine.
- Locate the function `format.names`. (In my copy of the bst file, the function starts on line 455.)
- In this function, locate the following 2 lines:

  ```
        nameptr #1 >
          {
  ```
- Immediately after these two lines, and hence before the line that says `namesleft #1 >`, insert the following 8 lines of code:

  ```
            nameptr #3
            #1 + =
            numnames #4
            > and
              { "others" 't :=
                #1 'namesleft := }
              'skip$
            if$
  ```
- Save the file `spbasic85.bst` either in the folder that contains the main tex file or a in a folder that's searched by BibTeX. If you select the latter option, be sure to also apply a suitable update to the filename database of your TeX distribution. (If you're not sure you understand the preceding sentence, I strongly suggest you select option 1...)
- In your main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{spbasic}` to `\bibliographystyle{spbasic85}` and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to propagate all changes.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
  @misc{abc,author="A and B and C",title="X",year=3000}
  @misc{abcd,author="A and B and C and D",title="Y",year=3001}
  @misc{abcde,author="A and B and C and D and E",title="Z",year=3002}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic85}

\begin{document}
\cite{abc}, \cite{abcd}, \cite{abcde}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I realized that the references are numbered in the order they are cited, but are listed in an alphabetic order. Is there a way to have the reference list in the oreder they are cited? At the moment I have the following options: \usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}

Comment: @Fabio61 - Please see the posting [Problem with Springer bibliography style(spbasic + natbib)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312819/5001) for an answer to your follow-up question. (Shameless self-citation alert!)