# Springer Basic Reference Style and natbib options issues

Tags: natbib, springer

I am quite new to LaTeX but am attempting to use the Springer Nature format available [here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support).
The journal I am submitting to requires that I use `sn-basic.bst` and have the references in square brackets, numbered, sorted and compressed. I am familiar with the `numbers` and `sort&compress` options within `natbib`, however, I am unable to get these options working with `sn-basic.bst`.

After reading up on issues like this, I attempted to change the natbib options within `sn-jnl.cls` for the Springer Basic format. On line 1658 I changed `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` to `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`. However, only the `numbers` option seems to take effect. That is, my references appear within square brackets as numbers, but they are not sorted and compressed where they should be.

Other things I have tried within my `.tex` file:

- `\usepackage[sort&compress, numbers]{natbib}`, but this produces clash warnings/errors since it is already loaded within `sn-jnl.cls`.
- `\setcitestyle{sort&compress, numbers}`
- `\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers, sort&compress}{natbib}`
- Leaving `sp-basic.bst` as is, but passing the `numbers` and `sort&compress` options with the `\documentclass` options like so: `\documentclass[sn-basic, numbers, sort&compress]{sn-jnl}`.
- Implementing the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312878/254294).

I am quite stuck on this and would appreciate if someone could please guide me on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you!

MWE... I hope: (Please let me know if I need to add more information to this!)

```
\documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl}
\begin{document}
    Words1 \cite{A2, A7, A5}, Words2 \cite{A1}
    \bibliography{ABC}
\end{document}
```

Without any adjustments to `sn-jnl.cls`, the above code will generate citations with the `authoryear` format. Having made the adjustments to line 1658 indicated above, the code will generate citations with only the `numbers` option seeming to take effect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't expect the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312878/5001) to be applicable, as it solves a very different problem, *viz.*, how to suppress alphabetical sorting of the formatted bibliographic entries. That's an issue that's separate from telling `natbib` that numeric-style citation call-outs should be sorted and (if possible) compressed.

Comment: If you're supposed to be using the `sn-basic` document class option with the`sn-jnl` document class, p. 12 of Springer's user manual for this document class states that this option produces authoryear-style citation call-outs, *not* numeric style citation call-outs. OTOH, if you are indeed supposed to be generating numeric-style citation call-outs, it would be *wrong* to use the `sn-basic` document class option; instead, you probably ought to use the `sn-standardnature` document class option. Do please re-read your actual instructions to figure out what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

1. On line 1658 of `sn-jnl.cls` change `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` to `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`
2. In `sn-basic.bst` find the two lines containing `SORT` in all-caps and delete them.