# Problem with Springer bibliography style （citation style: numbered, sort in alphabetical order）

Tags: bibliographies, springer

I am preparing my first paper. The format required by the Journal is that reference citations in the text should be identified by numbers in square brackets and the reference list at the end of the document MUST be placed in alphabetical order.
But in the Springer Nature LaTeX template 2021, there is no bibstyle satisfy this. The 'sn-basic, sn-apa, sn-chicago, sn-standardnature' has 'alphabetical order' but the citation style of them are 'authoryear'. The 'sn-mathphys, sn-aps, sn-vancouver, sn-standardnature' has the style 'numbered' but is 'accuarance order'.
How to modify these templates to meet the requirements of journals？ 'numbered' and 'alphabetical order'

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Are you also trying to submit to Springer's "Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery"?

Comment: No, another journal DCC.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and have no issues keeping document class as ''\documentclass[default,12pt]{sn-jnl}'' and bibliography style as ''\bibliographystyle{sn-basic}'' . By using the above scenario i was able to produce numbered alphabetical order list for my bibliography and in-line citations appeared jumbled (not in ascending order).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and have no issues keeping document class as `\documentclass[default,12pt]{sn-jnl}` and bibliography style as `\bibliographystyle{sn-basic}` . By using the above scenario i was able to produce numbered alphabetical order list for my bibliography and in-line citations appeared jumbled (not in ascending order). Further, if in-line citation is required to appear in ascending order, then based on [This posted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312819/problem-with-springer-bibliography-stylespbasic-natbib) edit the file sn-basic.bst and save it as 'sn-basicunsorted'. Next find and comment out 'SORT' (capitalized word only), then save it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that using `splncs03_unsrt.bst` ensured that references were cited in the order they appeared.